# How to generate error when .txt format is incorrect

Tags: java

I have a program that reads information from a text file and display it in an organized format.  How do I go about generating an error if the format of the text document does not meet a predetermined format.

Here is what I have so far:

```
package question;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question1 {

    public static void displayResults(double dinnerExpense, double lodgingExpense, double conferenceExpense) {
        System.out.println("Dinner expense: $" + dinnerExpense);
        System.out.println("Lodging expense: $" + lodgingExpense);
        System.out.println("Conference expense: $" + conferenceExpense);
    }

    public static void searchAndDisplayFile(String name) {
        try {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(name));
            double dinnerExpense = 0;
            double lodgingExpense = 0;
            double conferenceExpense = 0;
            while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                inFile.useDelimiter("; ");
                String activity = inFile.next();
                if (activity.equals("Dinner")) {
                    dinnerExpense += (inFile.nextDouble());
                }
                if (activity.equals("Lodging")) {
                    lodgingExpense += (inFile.nextDouble());
                }
                if (activity.equals("Conference")) {
                    conferenceExpense += (inFile.nextDouble());
                }
            }
            inFile.close();
            displayResults(dinnerExpense, lodgingExpense, conferenceExpense);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        searchAndDisplayFile(name);
        System.out.println("Make sure the file exists or is type correctly.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
throw new YourExceptionSubtype(...);
```

to throw an exception (if the exception is no runtimeexception, you have to add `throws YourExceptionSubtype` after the parameterlist. `YourExceptionSubtype` may be a javaAPI exception (IOException would fit), or an exception you implemented yourself (must have `Exception` as baseclass).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Exceptions**.An Exception is an error that occurs during the execution of your program.

You can create your own custom Exceptions by extending the **Exception Class** for example :

```
public class YourCustomException extends Exception
{
    public TestException(String msg)
    {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

So whatever you think is an error in your application for example (Dogs can't have 10 ears) you throw **YourCustomException**

```
if(dogEars > 3)
   throw new YourCustomException( "Dogs can't have more than 3 ears" );
```

Exceptions should be handled. The way you handle an exception is with a try/catch block

```
try
{
    Dog.dogEars = 5;
}
catch(YourCustomException yce)
{
    // handle the exception here
}
```

In you example for the word document if it is not formatted "Name; Category; Amount spent" you can do something like this:

```
if (activity.equals("Dinner")) // checking the Category column
{
    dinnerExpense+=(inFile.nextDouble());
}
else
{
   throw new FileFormattingException("The Category should be specified");
}
```

and in your main method that is calling the `displayResults(String name)` method you should surround the code with a try/catch block:

```
try
{
    searchAndDisplayFile(name);
}
catch(FileFormattingException ffe)
{
    ffe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Create a Class for you **FileFormattingException** Exception

```
public class YourCustomException extends Exception
{
    public TestException(String msg)
    {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about using this for a syntax.  I.e. If the word document is not formatted "Name; Category; Amount spent" that it generates an error?

Comment: Can you add how the file should be formatted and how you would search for the Name, Category and Amount spent ?

Comment: For example "John Doe; Dinner; 146.54; June 12, 2014"  Dinner could be subbed in with either conference or lodging.

Comment: I added the solution for this at the end of the answer